# How to migrate BIND configuration to dnssec-policy from auto-dnssec maintain without disruption?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec

BIND 9.16 introduced a new [`dnssec-policy`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.16/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch05.html#dnssec_policy_grammar) feature as a further more automated DNSSEC key management and signing facility over the long established [`auto-dnssec maintain`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.16/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch05.html#boolean_options) functionality.

The documentation does not appear to cover migrating from the old to the new, but the [related wiki page](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/wikis/DNSSEC-Key-and-Signing-Policy-(KASP)#key-generation) seems to indicate that already existing keys would be picked up by `dnssec-policy`.

That said, setting up a new zone with `dnssec-policy` is straightforward enough, but migrating an existing zone from `auto-dnssec maintain` to `dnssec-policy` does not seem to work as one might expect.
What I would have expected was that a policy compatible with the existing keys would keep using these keys.

What seems to happen is that all existing keys are immediately deleted from the zone because they have "expired" and are replaced with new keys, even though the new policy mandates a compatible set of keys (same algorithm and size) and the existing keys have no end of life properties defined (only `Created`, `Publish` and `Activate` timings in the .key files).

The policy I've used when testing looks like this (named to reflect what is what during testing):

```
dnssec-policy alg13-ksk-unlimited-zsk-60day {
     keys {
         ksk key-directory lifetime unlimited algorithm ECDSAP256SHA256;
         zsk key-directory lifetime P60D algorithm ECDSAP256SHA256;
     };
};
```

This is the log output when the configuration changed from `auto-dnssec maintain;` to `dnssec-policy alg13-ksk-unlimited-zsk-60day;`:

```
zone zone.example/IN (signed): reconfiguring zone keys
keymgr: DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/49004 (KSK) created for policy alg13-ksk-unlimited-zsk-60day
keymgr: DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/54646 (ZSK) created for policy alg13-ksk-unlimited-zsk-60day
Removing expired key 20481/ECDSAP256SHA256 from DNSKEY RRset.
DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/20481 (ZSK) is now deleted
Removing expired key 12506/ECDSAP256SHA256 from DNSKEY RRset.
DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/12506 (KSK) is now deleted
Fetching zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/49004 (KSK) from key repository.
DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/49004 (KSK) is now published
DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/49004 (KSK) is now active
Fetching zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/54646 (ZSK) from key repository.
DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/54646 (ZSK) is now published
DNSKEY zone.example/ECDSAP256SHA256/54646 (ZSK) is now active
zone zone.example/IN (signed): next key event: 22-Mar-2020 15:08:19.805
```

As can be seen the existing keys were immediately deleted (not even following the normal rollover procedure!) and replaced with new keys of the same type.
Considering that just instantly replacing the keys instead of following the intended rollover procedure breaks everything, it's apparent that simply switching the configuration to `dnssec-policy` is a no-go.

Looking at the key files, I note that an additional `.state` file is added side by side with both the old and the new keys.
I don't know if this file is a requirement for proper `dnssec-policy` operation somehow? Would having these files created beforehand somehow avoid this behavior?

The question at its core is: is there a way to migrate to using `dnssec-policy` in a non-disruptive manner? If so, how?

Comment: This may be a bug: https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/1706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior described in the question was a bug, which should be resolved as of BIND version 9.16.2.

From the [BIND 9.16.2 Release Notes](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.16.2/RELEASE-NOTES-bind-9.16.2.html):

> **Bug Fixes**
>
> [snip]
>
> - When trying to migrate an already-signed zone from auto-dnssec maintain to one based on dnssec-policy, the existing keys were immediately deleted and replaced with new ones. As the key rollover timing constraints were not being followed, it was possible that some clients would not have been able to validate responses until all old DNSSEC information had timed out from caches. BIND now looks at the time metadata of the existing keys and incorporates it into its DNSSEC policy operation. [GL #1706]

Comment: On my bind 9.18.19 it still removes the previous keys immediately. What is the keyword for the timing constraints mentioned above? I would like bind to create and publish the new keys, publish a CDS record for them, wait until the CDS is picked from registry the DS gets changed and then withdraw the old keys.